# Is it possible to get good shadows in Unity 3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shadow

guys!

I want to use Unity 3d for the AR project, for this, I need good shadows for the small objects. But when I start HDRP project and look at the demo scene I see terrible shadows... So the question is - is it really possible to get good shadows in Unity doing some adjustments or this the top what I may get? If it's possible, could someone point me out where to read how to set up good shadows for the small objects in Unity?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Mulitple factors comes when talking about shadows, such as general game **quality settings**, **antialiasing**, **light** settings, **Normal Bias**, **occlusion**, and more. You can change thoses settings in **Unity editor** directly.

You should check:

- Edit > Project Settings
- Ligh inspector settings (hard or soft shadows)
- Window > Rendering > Lighting Settings

You can kind of "play" with settings and see where you go, you can get good shadows for small objects in Unity3D. Don't forget that some settings could be very consuming depending on your hardware (you are doing AR so mobile), just keep in mind.

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

In Assets/URP, URP Render Pipeline Asset, Cascades=4, Shadow Resolution = 4096, Max Distance 5. Especially that last one made a BIG difference!